# Python variable + itself

Tags: python, variables

This maybe a very easy one but I'm unsure what to search for.

I want to do something like this:

```
temp = ""
for item in instance:
    temp = temp + item
```

I think I have seen it done like this before:

```
temp ++ item
```

but that does not work.

Comment: You've seen it where? I'm not sure that's valid in python.

Comment: `++` operator does not exist in Python

Comment: May have made it up then :( @Daniel has a good answer thanks

Comment: @GrantU check out an update to my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `++` operator does not exist in Python, but it does have the `+=` operator. You can use it as follows:

```
temp = ''
for item in instance:
    temp += item
```

In general, strings are immutable in Python (i.e., they cannot be changed). However, as Fenikso pointed out in the comments, this operator will create a new string object consisting of the old value of temp plus the new value of item.

You will probably be faster if you use a list comprehension, such as the one Alex Parakhnevich suggests in his answer.

Comment: I see, assumed I seen this done with strings, must have been wrong. I'll use a list instead

Comment: `+=` works for strings. It does not change the old one. It creates a new object by concatenation of two strings and assigns it to the `temp` variable. You can print `id(temp)` in the loop to verify.

Comment: The same happens to integers, they are immutable too, BTW.

Comment: Note that this solution is O(n^2) while `str.join` is O(n), see [An Optimization anecdote](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str.html).

Answer (score 4):

This will suit your needs:

```
temp = ''.join(instance)
```

Documentation on `join` method of `str`: [link](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).

Here's an example console log to be more clear:

```
>>> temp = ''

>>> instance = ['one', 'two', 'three']

>>> temp = ' '.join(instance)

>>> temp
>>> 'one two three'
```